# Microsoft Band 2 iOS SDK - consent for heart rate sensor not persisting

Tags: ios, sdk, sensors, microsoft-band

We used the Microsoft Band 2 SDK (iOS) to collect data from all the sensors of the band. The heart rate sensor requires that users grant access permission. According to the developer SDK documentation that permission is needed only once if the user agrees. In my testing of several bands (5, to be exact), the consent agreement does not persist and consent requests continue to appear even after data has been collected for a while without a problem.
Is there a way to persist the consent decision?

Comment: The user consent is persisted within the app so as long as the app is not deleted from the phone, it should persist. What iOS version are you using? Also, this shouldn't make a difference but are all 5 Bands connected to the same phone?

Comment: We have tried many versions 9 and 8. I am currently using version 9.3.4. Each band is connected to a distinct device. We have used five iPad minis. We have also tested some of the bands iPhones 6S Plus and 5S.  The result is the same. At an undetermined time the app asks again for permission to use the HR sensor. We lose a lot data then. Can we get historical HR data from the band. I notice that the Microsoft Health app is able to get historical data so that if a band is not connected to my phone, I can still get HR from the MSHealth app once synced. Your thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "At an undetermined time the app asks again...". The user consent verification and the request for user consent, if needed, are triggered by the app itself. So does your app verify user consent on every cold start, warm start or every couple of minutes?

Comment: To get historical HR you can use the Cloud API. More info can be found at: http://developer.microsofthealth.com/cloudAPI

Comment: The app uses activity or lack thereof to trigger the HR sensor. So if there is no movement for 5 minutes, the app would ask for consent to use the HR sensor and then if consent is present we would get HR data.

Comment: We are using MS Band 2s to get RR data as well as HR data. The cloud API does not tell us the RR Interval data. In addition, API data is given hourly as Max, Min, and Average. We want heart rate data at the same  time a symptom such as pain value is being entered. We would like to get contemporaneous data if at all possible.

Comment: In regards to "if there is no movement for 5 minutes, the app would ask for consent to use the HR sensor...", I assume you mean the app invokes the [self.client.sensorManager heartRateUserConsent]; API. If so, what is the result returned by the API? MSBUserConsentGranted, MSBUserConsentNotSpecified or MSBUserConsentDeclined.

Comment: Thank you so much, we appreciate your help. Yes, we are asking if we have consent. We have not logged the response but judge that if the alert appears, consent response is not persisted. Is there a way that it works for you that you could share?

Comment: Could you try the BandHeartRate app in the BandSamples project and see if you run into the same issue? https://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/download/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK%20and%20Samples%20for%20iOS.zip

Comment: I started there. I think the issue is because we are demanding a lot for the band because we are continuously asking for most of the band's sensors to operate at once. It is likely that the request does not get a response on time and it is treated as user consent not granted. In our scenario we need somehow to cache data on the band that we could retrieve later just as the MS Health app does. jonas@pitt.edu